# Physical meaning of the decoupling of the transverse velocity field in linearized Navier-Stokes equation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, field-theory, fourier-transform, navier-stokes

The Navier-Stokes equations:

\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        \partial_t \rho &= -\vec \nabla \cdot (\rho \vec u) \\
        \partial_t(\rho \vec u) + \vec \nabla \cdot (\rho \vec u \otimes \vec u) &= - \tilde \gamma \rho \vec u - \vec \nabla p + \vec \nabla \cdot  \vec \sigma^v
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
Where we assumed $T$ constant can be linearized around $\rho = \rho_0$ and $\vec u=0$ and separated in a transverse and longitudinal field. This reads:

\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        w\delta &\rho= \rho_0 k u_{\parallel}\\
        -iwu_\parallel &= -\nu^\parallel k ^2u_{\parallel} - ikc_s^2\delta \rho/\rho_0\\
        -iw\vec u_\perp &= - \nu^\perp k ^2\vec u_{\perp} 
    \end{split}
\end{equation}

We see that the transverse field is decoupled from the density and the longitudinal field. Physically, why is that so? What's the physical intuition behind that? Only that waves are longitudinal?

Comment: What is the physical problem being solved?

Comment: @ChetMiller The equations are taken from the appendix of this article: https://www.pnas.org/doi/10.1073/pnas.1911596116 which deals with active disks subject to a strong drag (I omitted the drag and the random part of the stress tensor). Since the energy is non conserved, it becomes a fast variable and they can get rid of the temperature equation. In any case, my question was a bit more general than that. What can we say about a fluid which exhibits this kind of decoupling in its linearized limit? Is it usual? Why do we expect that, etc..